# How to Sync Apple Mail account with Outlook account

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, apple-mail

I have an @me.com account that I would like synced (shared the same inbox and folders) with an @outlook account? This is so I can have Cortana read my iCloud emails to me. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: It Cortana can only read your outlook.com account emails the only option is to forward the me.com emails to your outlook.com address. This will be an account setting in your me.com account.

Comment: Agree with @music2myear. Also, if you are working with Outlook desktop client, you could configure your me.com account and create a rule to forward thoses messages automatically there.

Comment: Your replies are greatly appreciate it, thank you.  |  If the messages are forwarded, wouldn’t that mean that I would have the same message twice in my Apple inbox and my Outlook inbox? I guess my question is, if I made changes to one account, will reflect on the other account?

Comment: Yes, forwarding mail is just copying the mail to another account so that you can read the mail there. But any changes in your Outlook account (e.g. read/unread mail) will not affect the original mail in your Apple Mail account, they are still 2 separate accounts.